# how can aws glue job upload several tables in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue

Is it possible to load multiple tables in Redshift using AWS Glue job?

These are the steps I followed.

1. Crawled json from S3 and the data has been translated into data catalog table.
2. I created a job that will upload the data catalog table in redshift but it only limits me to upload 1 table for every job. In the job properties (in adding a job), This job runs option I chose is: *A proposed script generated by AWS Glue.*

I am not familiar with python and I am new to AWS Glue. but I have several tables needed to be uploaded.

here is a sample script:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [TempDir, JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "sampledb", table_name = "abs", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "sampledb", table_name = "abs", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("value", "int", "value", "int"), ("sex", "string", "sex", "string"), ("age", "string", "age", "string"), ("highest year of school completed", "string", "highest year of school completed", "string"), ("state", "string", "state", "string"), ("region type", "string", "region type", "string"), ("lga 2011", "string", "lga 2011", "string"), ("frequency", "string", "frequency", "string"), ("time", "string", "time", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("value", "int", "value", "int"), ("sex", "string", "sex", "string"), ("age", "string", "age", "string"), ("highest year of school completed", "string", "highest year of school completed", "string"), ("state", "string", "state", "string"), ("region type", "string", "region type", "string"), ("lga 2011", "string", "lga 2011", "string"), ("frequency", "string", "frequency", "string"), ("time", "string", "time", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
## @type: ResolveChoice
## @args: [choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2"]
## @return: resolvechoice2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
## @type: DropNullFields
## @args: [transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3"]
## @return: dropnullfields3
## @inputs: [frame = resolvechoice2]
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
## @type: DataSink
## @args: [catalog_connection = "redshift", connection_options = {"dbtable": "abs", "database": "dbmla"}, redshift_tmp_dir = TempDir, transformation_ctx = "datasink4"]
## @return: datasink4
## @inputs: [frame = dropnullfields3]
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = "redshift", connection_options = {"dbtable": "abs", "database": "dbmla"}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

aws glue database: sampledb

table name in aws glue: abs

redshift database: dbmla

Please site an example on how to upload them. thanks!

Comment: Did you try editing the generated code, to add more datasources as needed for the number of tables? and try running in one job?  You can modify the generated python script before running the job. I haven't tried it, but hope it works.

Comment: thanks a lot Yuva. You have bbeen really helpful..  I will try this way too and will let you know the output.

Comment: However, I am thinking of not inputting the specific table names in the script. My plan is too call out every data catalog tables. The crawler will run at an hourly rate so the incoming table may contain new set of data or just an update of the old table.
Having this setup, it will be difficult to input every table name in the script that has been crawled in glue because the job will not contain the new tables. I am thinking if there is a way to have the job loads set of tables, just rewrite the existing ones, and upload new data catalog tables.

Comment: I don't think that is possible out of the box from the glue generated code.  You may need to write your own custom code, use AWS Glue APIs to get list of tables, and loop through the list, perform transformation, etc.  I haven't tried it, but you can give a try.  Please refer here for more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_GetTables.html.

Comment: http://dbbest.com/blog/aws-glue-etl-service here is a same solution as I mentioned above, I just saw, so am sharing for your reference

Comment: it works!!! thank you Yuva!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to AWS Glue FAQ, you can modify the generated code, and run the job.

> Q: How can I customize the ETL code generated by AWS Glue?
>
> AWS Glue’s ETL script recommendation system generates Scala or Python
>   code. It leverages Glue’s custom ETL library to simplify access to
>   data sources as well as manage job execution. You can find more
>   details about the library in our documentation. You can write ETL code
>   using AWS Glue’s custom library or write arbitrary code in Scala or
>   Python by using inline editing via the AWS Glue Console script editor,
>   downloading the auto-generated code, and editing it in your own IDE.
>   You can also start with one of the many samples hosted in our Github
>   repository and customize that code.

So please try add code snippets for additional tables to the same script as follows,

```
datasource1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "sampledb", table_name = "abs2", transformation_ctx = "datasource1")
applymapping2 = ApplyMapping.apply(.. transformation_ctx = "applymapping2")
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping2, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = "redshift", connection_options = {"dbtable": "abs2", "database": "dbmla"}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink4")

datasource2 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "sampledb", table_name = "abs2", transformation_ctx = "datasource1")
applymapping2 = ApplyMapping.apply(.. transformation_ctx = "applymapping2")
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping2, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = "redshift", connection_options = {"dbtable": "abs2", "database": "dbmla"}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink4")

datasource3 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "sampledb", table_name = "abs2", transformation_ctx = "datasource1")
applymapping2 = ApplyMapping.apply(.. transformation_ctx = "applymapping2")
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping2, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = "redshift", connection_options = {"dbtable": "abs2", "database": "dbmla"}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink4")

job.commit()
```

Change the variable names accordingly so as to be unique. Thanks

Comment: Will Job Bookmarks work for every table in this case?

Comment: And will the jobs run in parallel?

Comment: For me this is not working. I am getting error in ApplyMapping.apply line. Issue is with double dots. Not sure about how this is working for you?

Comment: user2768132 Please refer to the AWS Glue API for correct usage of ApplyMapping.apply().  The code snippet provided above is a template only, hope you saw the last line in my answer to update the variable names accordingly.  Thanks

Comment: Or please check the original post sample code. Thanks

Comment: @Yuva perfect. Thanks