# Multiple files in S3 are getting created after running an ETL job that uses connection of RDS MySQL

Tags: amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue

I am new to AWS glue and tried to see if I could create our data lake in S3. For this I created an ETL job to run on small MySQL table in RDS. After job completion multiple CSV files have been created in S3 and most of them are empty.

I want to understand :

1. Why data is partitioned in multiple files?
2. Can I run job on multiple tables? In AWS console it allows only to select one table as source datastore. Does that mean I need to create a job for each table?

Answer (score 1):

1. This is due to the distribution of the key of your data. As far as I know, you can only load-balance the key by yourself manually.
2. Possible Duplicate: [how can aws glue job upload several tables in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459840/how-can-aws-glue-job-upload-several-tables-in-redshift/50462703#50462703).

Comment: Hi @Kishore thanks for answering the question. Can you please elaborate point 1 with an example?

Comment: Hi Aditya, It's due to the number of workers/reducers which operate inside your underlying spark job. each one would be throwing out an individual file. If you want to reduce the number of output files, try using coalesce(n) - function, n is the number of output files you want.